# Can I find the frequency generated by tapping a battery on a coin?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, home-experiment

According To [How Stuff Works](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/radio1.htm) , if you tap a 9 volt battery on a coin it will transmit Radio waves. I was wondering, because I don't have a radio with me at the moment, Is there a way I could discover the frequency that it is transmitting using math? Possibly involving Maxwell's Equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spark-gap transmitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter) like that transmit in a wide band. Your source states that the specific transmitter can be received, e.g., in the standard AM band, but I did not check that experimentally. You don't need fine tuning though:-)